# How to convert dayname to number?

Tags: date-and-time, conversion

When I input `DayName[{2012,12,24}]` I get `Monday` as output. What is the most effective way to convert Monday into 1, Tuesday into 2 etc.?

To do this, I can create a length-7 array to store all the day-name and then do some matching and return the matched position. But that approach is too clumsy. Is there any other lighter and faster way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most efficient way is not to use `DayName` but this:

```
DateValue[{2012, 12, 24}, "ISOWeekDay"]
```

---

Regarding Robert's comment

> Well, that was a correct answer but not on the exact question. What if I don't have a date but just a weekday as e.g. Monday how do I now get the ISOWeekDay number. Without explicitly coding. Is there a a ready to use MMA function f with f[Monday] == 1

the shortest solution I found is

```
ISODay = System`DateObjectDump`$dowAssociation;

ISODay[Monday]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Well, that was a correct answer but not on the exact question. What if I don't have a date but just a weekday as e.g. Monday how do I now get the ISOWeekDay number. Without explicitly coding. Is there a a ready to use MMA function f with f[Monday] == 1

Comment: @RobertNowak See my edit above.

Comment: May I ask by which black spell incantation you discovered this `dowAssociation`?

Comment: I was quite sure that at some point, WL's functions need a conversion from day-name to number, because how else would they implement the `"ISOWeekDay"`. So I started digging with `PrintDefinitions[DateValue]` and followed the trail...

Answer (score 0):

```
ISODay[day_] := Mod[With[{o = {1, 1, 0}}, DateDifference[
  DayPlus[o, 1, Monday],
  DayPlus[o, 1, day]
  ][[1]]], 7] + 1
```